# metric of MotionEvent API getPressure, getSize

Tags: android

I'm working on a program which used the functions as title.

There's a problem that the tunctions above do not have their metrics on API website.

To avoid misunderstanding, here is an example about "metric" I metioned before.

Ex. size = pixel, pressure = kilogram(kg)

I have no idea about the metric at all.

Please show me where can I find the information I need.

Or, tell me under this topic.

thx again.

Answer (score 4):

[getPressure(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29) doc says:

> Returns the current pressure of this event for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). The pressure generally ranges from 0 (no pressure at all) to 1 (normal pressure), however values higher than 1 may be generated depending on the calibration of the input device.

So the pressure is measured in an abstract metric.

[getSize(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getSize%28int%29) doc says:

> Returns a scaled value of the approximate size for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). This represents some approximation of the area of the screen being pressed; the actual value in pixels corresponding to the touch is normalized with the device specific range of values and scaled to a value between 0 and 1. The value of size can be used to determine fat touch events.

And the size seems also to be measured with an abstract metric.

Comment: I pressed enter before I finished my comment. sry.
This is my fully comment below:                              


I've read that API descriptions before.
But thanks for your kindly reply anyway. :D

I do this for my research.

And my professor made me to find out the metric to put it in my paper.

It's nessesary to get the real metric which this API used.
so...
How can I get deeper information? and where can I find it?

Comment: If the value is measured by abstract metric.

Maybe there's an algorithm for computing the answer.

But the problem is still that "where can I find it :(

show me if you know that.

sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You can browse the Android source here (http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/).

Comment: @user443150 Have you find out what is the metric for that? I have also same problem and sadly the Android source stoped working.